# Why does my database gets empty on adding data to another database?

Tags: database, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, web-deployment

I have two databases connected to my flask server when I try to add data to my images.db database the data from users.db gets deleted automatically. Earlier both the tables were in the same database but now even after making two separate databases, the problem is not resolved.

Here is the code for models.py

```
class Image(db.Model): #images.db
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_observed = db.Column(db.DateTime, unique=True, nullable=False)
    jd = db.Column(db.Float, unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        attrs = vars(self)
        return ', '.join("%s: %s" % item for item in attrs.items())
    

# User table in the database
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __bind_key__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    history = db.Column(db.String(240))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "User({self.username}, {self.email})".format()

def file_to_Image_obj(fits_image_filename):
    
    hdul = fits.open(fits_image_filename)
    hdr = hdul[0].header
    (y_end,x_end) = hdul[0].data.shape 
    hdul.close()
    wcs = WCS(hdr)
    
    n_of_div = 5

    this_image = Image(
    date_observed = parse(read_header('DATE-OBS',hdr)),
    jd = read_header('JD',hdr)
)
    
    return this_image

# takes as input directory path and adds all fits files (.fits extension) to the db
def add_dir_to_db(dirpath, append=True):
    print('Adding Images to Database')
    if not append:
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
    
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dirpath):
        for filename in filenames:
            filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            #changed to proc.fits for demo
            if filepath.endswith('.fits'):
                try :
                    this_image = file_to_Image_obj(filepath)
                    print(filepath, this_image.date_observed)
                    db.session.add(this_image)
                except Exception as e :
                    with open("error_report.txt","a") as logf:
                        logf.write("Failed to make db object {0}: {1}\n".format(filepath, str(e)))
                    print (str(e))
                
                
    db.session.commit()

def add_user_to_db(username, email, password):
    print('Adding User')
    user = User(username=username, email=email, password=password)
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: why do you have 2 databases ? it seems overly complicated

Comment: @CyrilJouve I earlier had one database with two tables, however, I thought of making two separate databases just to try if the above problem gets resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Found the answer to the question. The function add_dir_to_db() has db.drop_all() without any bind key set. For the default database all I needed was to set bind_key = None

```
def add_dir_to_db(dirpath, append=True):
    print('Adding Images to Database')
    if not append:
        db.drop_all(bind_key=None)
        db.create_all(bind_key=None)
```